# In Vim, how can one prevent auto indent for HTML tags, but maintain for sections of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, vim

Basically when I'm editing an .HTML file I do not want Vim to indent HTML tags, but I do want it to indent for Javascript code.

I want to stop this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
```

I would prefer the HTML just go the beginning of the next line when I hit enter:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
```

But I want Vim to keep doing this for Javascript:

```
function fooBar() {
    var myVar = 10;    
}
```

I currently have this line in my .gvimrc:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Can I selectively disable Vim's indent for only HTML tags? When I did Google research on this I mostly ended up with tutorials on disabling indention for pasting code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that simply doing `set filetype=javascript` would be enough. But you should put your JavaScript in separate *.js files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set indentexpr=|set cindent
```

I believe it should have the effect you're looking for, it does not indent based on html tags, but it will still indent after things like open curly braces, and it preserves html syntax highlighting.  To make this permanent you could use an autocommand in your vimrc like `au BufEnter *.html set indentexpr=|set cindent`.

There are 4 levels of indentation.  They are, in order from lowest to highest precedence, `autoindent`, `smartindent`, `cindent`, and `indentexpr`.  Thus, all that you should need to do is make sure `indentexpr` is not set and then you can just set `cindent`.  `cindent` uses the characters `{,},),:,#` by default for indentation, so it will indent things like curly braces without indenting html.